# click function doesn't refer to the servlet (IDEA, java)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, servlets

The command $.get('MyController1', function (responseText) doesn't send to my servlet. I use ajax and after clicking the button it should send to my servlet ('MyController1' or 'MyController2'...) and the servlet sends to .jsp-page and some text should appear. 
This is my start page (index.jsp):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {                        
        $('#1').click(function () {               
            $.get('MyController1', function (responseText) {
                $('#main').html(" ");                    
                $('#main').append(responseText);  
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {                        
        $('#2').click(function () {               
            $.get('MyController2', function (responseText) {
                $('#main').html(" ");                    
                $('#main').append(responseText);  
            });
        });
    });
</script>    
</head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="ButtonTest1" id="1">
        <input type="button" value="ButtonTest2" id="2">   
        <div id="main"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a part of my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyController1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyController1</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyController1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myController1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And this one of my servlets:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyController1 extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/button1.jsp").forward(req, resp);

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your AJAX call as

```
$.get('myController1', function (responseText) {
       ^^ lowercase m
```

to match the `<url-pattern>` configured for `MyController1` servlet in your `web.xml`.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! I spent several hours to find the problem! :) You saved my life :)